# SFTP support for azure data factory

Tags: azure, sftp

I have a SFTP server. I have my files uploaded there. I want to use azure data factory to connect with the SFTP server and read the files from the SFTP server and save them in the Azure Blob storage.

Is there a way to perform this using azure pipeline/activity configuration?

Answer (score 1):

ADF has recently Added SFTP Support.Refer
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-sftp-connector

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

[Data Factory now has native support for sftp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-sftp-connector).

---

It doesn't appear that Data factory supports sftp natively, however:

> If you need to move data to/from a data store that Copy Activity
>   doesn't support, use a custom activity in Data Factory with your own
>   logic for copying/moving data. For details on creating and using a
>   custom activity, see Use custom activities in an Azure Data Factory
>   pipeline.

Also, [Azure Logic Apps do support sftp natively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp) which you could use to drop into blob storage, however I'm guessing (I'm soon to find out) that you'll loose the knowledge that the sftp server failing is a route cause when monitoring the factory.

[SFTP planned feature in the azure feedback portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/17228093-add-support-for-sftp), if it is important to you I would recommend voting it up.